# OutputStream In android dosn't work

Tags: android, json

I'm coding an app in android based JSON. I got Wamp Server. and my code is below...
In MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText edUsername, edPassword;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
    edPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
}

public void onclickLogin(View v)
{
    String username = edUsername.getText().toString();
    String password = edPassword.getText().toString();
    String type = "login";

    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, password);
}
```

and BackgroundWorker class is below :

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;

BackgroundWorker(Context ctx)
{
    context = ctx;
}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String type = params[0];

    String login_url = "http://localhost/login.php";

    if(type.equals("login"))
    {
        try {

            Log.d("myapp1", "do 1");
            String user_name = params[1];
            String password = params[2];

            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

            Log.d("myapp1", "do 2");
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            Log.d("myapp1", "do 3");

            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8") + "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("user_pass", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            String result = ""  ;
            String line = "";

            while ( (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null )
            {
                result += line;
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return result;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    return null;
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
```

}

in BackgroundWorker class the OutputStream method dosn't work...
I tested login.php in browser and it's work... but OutputStream dosn't work... please help... thanks.

Comment: Please update your question with an precise error description. "does not work" is not very precise!

Comment: Can you elaborate more? You could start with posting your logs.

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` points to the same device, you are running the code on. If you run the code on the phone, it will reference the **phone**.

`localhost` is treated as **myself**. So if you try to connect to `localhost` from the phone, it will try to connect to the phone (to **itself**). If you try to connect from the PC, it will connect to the **PC** (to **itself**).

To connect from phone to PC you have to use PC IP address instead of `localhost`

Comment: I get my IPv4 in cmd (by ipconfig) and replace with localhost and my app dosn't work again... show message null... get public IP from net and replace that and dosn't work again...  plase help... thanks.

Comment: Is your Android device connected to the same network as your PC?

Comment: I am using Genymotion for app building

Comment: @user2849030 Genymotion is using `10.0.3.2` as host IP

Comment: I replaced and not working yet...        String login_url="http://10.0.3.2/login.php"     also 10.0.2.2  and not working again

Comment: yes I have done it...but not working...What might this be the reason?

Comment: @user2849030, possibly the server does not accept connections from LAN. Check if you can access it from mobile browser